# Use WHERE clause only if item is set, otherwise select all rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, where-clause

In my Apex Oracle application I have a report using this sql query:

```
select ID,
   NAME,
   ADDRESS,
   TYPE,
   COMPANY_ID as "Company"
from WORKSTATIONS where COMPANY_ID = :P11_FILTER
```

which filters data by value of :P11_FILTER item. Now I need to select all rows if :P11_FILTER is not set or is NULL. How could I modify the where clause in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `or`:

```
where COMPANY_ID = :P11_FILTER or :P11_FILTER is null
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `coalesce()` or `nvl()`:

```
where COMPANY_ID = coalesce(:P11_FILTER, COMPANY_ID)
```

`coalesce(:P11_FILTER, COMPANY_ID)` returns `COMPANY_ID` when `:P11_FILTER` is `null`.

Note that this `where` clause does not match in the situation where both `COMPANY_ID` and the parameter are `NULL`. This is different from the `OR` solution, that would returns the `NULL` row here.

Comment: This assumes that `COMPANY_ID` is not null. Perhaps that is the case in the OP's situation, but the assumption should be stated explicitly. In any case, Gordon's solution is likely more efficient.

Comment: @mathguy: indeed. I edited my answer to be specific about this.